# How to fix MSSQLLocalDB?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-express, localdb

On my machine MSSQLLocalDB got corrupted:

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb i
    MSSQLLocalDB
    Projects
    ProjectsV12
    v11.0
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb i mssqllocaldb
    The required LocalDB version "0.0" is not installed.
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Is there anything I can do short of reinstalling Visual Studio / Sql Server / Sql Express to fix it?

I should mention that any Visual Studio functionality that is dependent on LocalDb is not working because of this, for example CodeMaps

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can occur if you've just installed LocalDB and haven't started the instance yet. I'm not sure if rebooting would have restarted it for me (I imagine it would have), but the following worked without needing to:

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe s MSSQLLocalDB
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
```

That should be all you need - but here is the full diagostics steps I used in the process.

---

This is before installing new version of LocalDB (2014)

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe i
v11.0
```

Afterwards

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe i
MSSQLLocalDB
v11.0
```

Then I immediately get this error

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe i MSSQLLocalDB
The required LocalDB version "0.0" is not installed.
```

Strange! What about version 11 - that's ok

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe i v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.5343.0
Shared name:
Owner:              RR2014\sweaver
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    3/10/2016 3:00:29 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#60C1AC49\tsql\query
```

Here's the versions

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe v
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5343.0)
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
```

Let's try starting it

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe s MSSQLLocalDB
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
```

And try again...

```
C:\Users\sweaver>sqllocaldb.exe i MSSQLLocalDB
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              RR2014\sweaver
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    3/10/2016 3:10:55 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#1D3F49F3\tsql\query
```

Phew! That was easy!

Answer (score 5):

What I ended up doing follows. Note, that I'm sure this is not a correct way of doing this, but rather a messy hack. It allowed me getting my CodeMaps working again though, so I'm happy.

I deleted the `mssqllocaldb`

```
sqllocaldb d mssqllocaldb
```

The system won't let me create it again so I created another one:

```
sqllocaldb с mssqllocaldb1
```

I went to `"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\"` and backed up `MSSQLLocalDB` folder. Then I copied `MSSQLLocalDB1` folder to `MSSQLLocalDB`.

In registry I found the new instance under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\` and changed the `DataDirectory` value to reflect the new path, that is to end with `MSSQLLocalDB` instead of `MSSQLLocalDB1`.

After that I was able to start `MSSQLLocalDB` successfully and CodeMaps worked:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb s mssqllocaldb
>
> LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by deleting the folder and a reg key. Followed by an install.

Delete the folder

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB

Delete the registry key that has MSSQLLocalDB like
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances{B0A12082-AC5B-4E05-A0C9-ABFB6816EE16}

Running from cmd

C:>sqllocaldb c MSSQLLocalDB

LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" created with version 13.0.2151.0.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the registry key GUID under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\` to the correct value of `ParentInstance` which was working for me. Usualy this happens when you upgrade to higher versions. I have to change ParentInstance value from `MSSQL12E.LOCALDB` to `MSSQL13E.LOCALDB`